# requirements.txt vs Pipfile in heroku flask webapp deployment?

Tags: heroku, pip, python-venv, requirements.txt, pipfile

I'm trying to deploy a Flask webapp to Heroku and I have seen conflicting information as to which files I need to include in the git repository.

My webapp is built within a virtual environment (venv), so I have a `Pipfile` and a `Pipfile.lock`. Do I also need a `requirements.txt`? Will one supersede the other?

Another related question I have is what would occur if a certain package failed to install in the virtual environment: can I manually add it to the `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`? Would this effectively do the same thing as `pipenv install ...` or is that doing something else beyond adding the package to the list of requirements (considering Heroku is installing the packages upon deployment).

Comment: For the second point, I strongly urge you to solve any issues you may have building libraries locally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not need `requirements.txt`.

The `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` that Pipenv uses are designed to replace `requirements.txt`. If you include all three files, Heroku will ignore the `requirements.txt` and just use Pipenv.

If you have build issues with a particular library locally I urge you to dig into that and get everything working on your local machine. But this isn't technically required... as long as the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` contain the right information (including hashes), Heroku will try to install your dependencies.